# can i make an iphone-app NOT deletable, like the preinstalled ons or some cydia-apps?

Tags: iphone, ios4, jailbreak

at first: this app will NEVER reach the appstore, so apples restrictions are eglible.
the app should only be for demonstration purpuose, but i want, that no mean person playing with the device can delete it. some apps in cydia show, that it is possible.

second thing: i did only read something about the os4-features, because until this time there is an ios4-problem with this project. but: can i write the software so, that it ignores the homebutton completely ?
so that the customer doesnt get the chance to play around and can not get off the software (until he finds maybe a gesture or sth like that).

Answer (score 2):

If the device is jailbroken, the user can do anything, including deleting "undeletable" apps. If the device is not jailbroken, you're probably not going to be able to access whatever setting makes an app undeletable.

Comment: on my privat jailbroken phone, i can not delete those "marked" apps on the go... so - as you say it, it is not perfectly so

Comment: If you have a jailbroken phone, you have root-level access to its contents. You can delete anything you want.

Comment: a user with any console could, maybe.
nut no normal enduser can delete them like the normal apps when tapping long on the screen and then on the (X). i just want that fast deleting to be gone